# Why does Nagios show localhost down?

Tags: debian, nagios

I am running Nagios 4 in Debian Jessie. It shows the localhost down but all the services it check are OK.
The Nagios plugins are installed.
I followed this tutorial for the installation: http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/nagioscore/4/en/quickstart-ubuntu.html

Answer (score 1):

Connect as a regular user, *not root*.
If the command `ping localhost` says something along the lines of `ping: icmp open socket: Operation not permitted` then check out [Ping: icmp open socket: Operation not permitted (Linux)](http://ben.goodacre.name/tech/Ping:_icmp_open_socket:_Operation_not_permitted_(Linux))

It basically states that you need to add the "`s`" flag on the `ping` binary, usually located on `/bin/ping` on Debian systems: `sudo chmod u+s /bin/ping`

Comment: Certainly a useful tip, but does it address the OP's issue..?

Comment: @Greenonline It should. AFAIK, Nagios uses the ping command to check a server's up or down status.

Answer (score 0):

That check will just try to ping localhost. Does that work? If not, it could be due to many things: your firewall may block it, or you may have disabled your configuration for localhost.

Comment: It shows `PING OK  06-25-2015 10:59:54  0d 0h 34m 29s  1/4  PING OK - Packet loss = 0%, RTA = 0.08 ms` in the status detail, but in the hosts lists, in the status informatios for the localhost it shows `check_ping: <max_packets> (%s) must be a non-negative number `

Comment: That means you've neglected to add a parameter to a check_ping invocation. Look for a "check_ping" line in your configuration, and make it say "check_ping!1" or some such. Alternatively, just remove the "is localhost up" line. That's a pretty useless test anyway.

Comment: In the localhost.cfg the line is `check_command check_ping!100.0,20%!500.0,60%`

Comment: It most likely means that the `check_ping` plugin definition (in an other nagios config file) calls the `check_ping` binary (external program) in an incorrect way. On my Debian box, the `check_ping` plugin definition is found in `/etc/nagios-plugins/config/ping.cfg`. Check that file, run the `check_ping` binary that it references to get an idea for its options, and verify that the arguments it's given are not screwed up.